# in discord.py how to to delete others all message

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make bot that delete specific server or channel's bot's all message.

but I can find just deleting event message or delete channel's message.

```
import asyncio
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.content
    guild = message.guild
    author = message.author
    channel = message.channel
    if content == "!delete":
        await #delete all bot's message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all the bot's message in a specific channel can be done with `channel.purge`

```py
async def on_message(message):
   channel = message.channel
   if message.content == '!delete':
      if len(message.mentions) == 0:
         await channel.purge(limit=100, check= lambda x: x.author.id == client.user.id)
      else:
         mentioned = message.mentions[0]
         await channel.purge(limit=100, check= lambda x: x.author.id == mentioned.id)
```

If you want to delete messages in all channels, just loop it with `guild.channels`

### References:

- [channel.purge](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge)
- [message.mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.mentions)

Note:
The check function should return a bool that tells use whether we should delete the message or not, and takes the message as the parameter.

Comment: thanks. so i get user.id from
"message.mentions[0]"
and how can i edit 
"await channel.purge(limit=100, check= lambda x: x.author.id == client.user.id)"
this line? sorry. it's too hard to me

Comment: I edited my answer, I suggest you use [commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html?highlight=commands) for this, would make your job much easier

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all messages in specific channel:

```
guilds_list = [CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL2_ID, CHANNEL3_ID]
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id in guilds_list:
        await message.delete()
```

Now bot will delete all messages in specific channel, if you want to delete only bot's messages:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id in guilds_list and message.author is client.user:
        await message.delete()
```

***Note***: this process is automatic. So bot will delete every message it send to specific channel.

Comment: This won't work, you have to check if `message.channel.id in guilds_list` and even then, it will only delete the new messages that are sent, I think the OP wants to delete the bot's previous messages.